# Older question closed as duplicate for new one

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I recently had a question I asked in 2013 closed as a duplicate.
[Error loading DLL in python, not a valid win32 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849077/error-loading-dll-in-python-not-a-valid-win32-application)

However the closure is a bit odd to me as the question it was marked as a duplicate of was asked in 2019.
[Python Ctypes - loading dll throws OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57187566/python-ctypes-loading-dll-throws-oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win)

I'm assuming that older post should take precedence when it comes to which is considered a duplicate?

Comment: The better question should be used as the duplicate target.

Comment: The answer to the latter question seems like it's a lot more detailed. If the two questions ask for the same information, why wouldn't the newer one be preferable?

Comment: I was just unclear on what makes a duplicate question.  I read "duplicate" as, this has already a been asked and answered here.  I get that the answer on the newer question is more complete.  Having read through both the question and answers though, if I were searching that question, the newer question seems to pre-emptively reject the top answer (which is the right answer) and might throw off future readers. Also concerned the top answer might lead to a TL;DR effect.   Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Ultimately what matters is getting users to the best content we have to offer to solve their problem. If that means closing an older question as a duplicate of a newer one because we were too slow to close it and it received a better answer (and ideally is a better more general question,) then that's what we do